# NSTask run script

Tags: objective-c, nstask

I am trying to run the following command with NSTask:

```
$sudo launchctl load /Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents/com.devdaily.crontabtest.plist
```

Below is the code I use:

```
NSTask *server = [NSTask new];
[server setLaunchPath:@"/bin/launchctl"];
[server setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"load",@"com.devdaily.crontabtest.plist",nil]];
[server setCurrentDirectoryPath:@"/Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents/"];

NSPipe *outputPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[server setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];
[server setStandardOutput:outputPipe];

[server launch];
[server waitUntilExit]; // Alternatively, make it asynchronous.
[server release];
```

However, it doesn't work because of the `sudo` command. How can I fix this?

Comment: Using `sudo` in a non-console environment is not very useful because there's no easy way to enter a password (yes, you could use the standard input pipe, but it's much better to use OS X's builtin escalation utilities). Second, I'm guessing that sudo isn't being loaded by `sh` because it's not loading a path.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, *you can't*. Because there is no way to enter the password.

However, you can still run your bash command by using `NSAppleScript` instead of `NSTask`:
Write an applescript like:

`do shell script` `[your command]` `with administrator privileges`

*You will be asked for the admin password.*

**Example:**

```
NSDictionary *error = [NSDictionary new]; 
NSString *script =  @"do shell script \"launchctl load /Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents/com.devdaily.crontabtest.plist\" with administrator privileges";  
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript new] initWithSource:script]; 
if ([appleScript executeAndReturnError:&error]) {
  NSLog(@"success!"); 
} else {
  NSLog(@"failure!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read Apple's [Secure Coding Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Introduction.html) and follow the recommendation for [Elevating Privileges Safely](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html).

In other words, don't use `sudo` or something like it. Use `SMJobBless()` to install and enable your launch agent. See also the [SMJobBless sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html).